# Wireless USB: usb wifi pair device that creates a usb connection?

Tags: usb, wireless

Wireless USB: usb wifi pair device that creates a usb connection?

I am looking for this:
the device is not a wifi device that connects to any network.
it is a wifi that connects only on the other hardware piece of the same kind.
it is a pair: 2 parts, both identical, both connect on USB and have a exclusive wifi.
each part only connects on the other part.

I need to make the connection to be detected like a USB connection, but to behave like a "wireless USB" connection. It still needs to be recognized like USB and not WIFI, because the apps on both devices need to recognize that they are using a USB connection and work properly, work like expected, as usual.

Obs.: I just thought that buying 2 arduino with USB connection and 2 WIFI modules with 5GHz each, we would be able to create a good thing :)

PS: connecting 2 devices thru a 2.5m USB cable to be able to walk near it while having the good usb connection is messed up because I may damage the pc, the smartphone, the cable and even hurt myself.
But, if I could have a 5GHz Wifi connection (on both old devices that only have 2.4GHz wifi) while using the USB port to make both devices (ex.: a pc and a smartphone) detect the connection as USB, it would work almost like at a USB cable quality/speed I guess!

Comment: Your best bet probably would be a Wireless USB dock, but they're basically unsupported and unaffordable these days. You might have some luck with WiGig hubs, but those require specific hardware.

Comment: If you're going to use an arduino or SBC on at least one end to act as a "USB host" for the actual USB thing you may was well use WiFi to talk to the SBC itself. Making a direct wireless connection between two arduinos would be extra work and "re-inventing the wheel". This sort of adapter is so rarely needed that it's not really a product you can go buy, you do have to make something custom. Usually there is an alternative product or more direct solution to talk to the device if you find yourself needing a USB device to be far away from a PC. What is the device you're trying to make wireless?

Comment: @Romen connecting a smartphone thru a 2.5m usb cable in the PC to be able to walk near it while having the good usb connection is messed up because I may damage the pc, the smartphone, the cable and even hurt myself... Thru wifi is slower but works too. Now, if I could have a 5GHz Wifi connection while using the USB to make the pc and the smartphone detect the connection as USB (or any other 2 devices), it would work almost like a USB cable quality/speed I guess!

Comment: You're assuming that some home-made 5Ghz connection between the two arduinos or whatever is going to be faster than WiFi, which I think is a really really tough thing to accomplish unless you're an expert in engineering these things. The reason "wireless USB" adapters don't exist is because they need to be extremely complex devices that can tolerate signal loss, so complex that a typical WiFi or Bluetooth chipset starts looking like an equal/redundant concept. Try using 5Ghz wifi if you need it to be faster.

Comment: @Romen if I am not wrong, the signal loss or instability could be handled by the arduino software by creating an IOWait, like in the device will not send nor receive any data but will also not disconnect, will just stay there waiting and making the PC or the smartphone wait too right? Btw, the 5GHz is Wifi, but is faster than the ones on my PC and my smartphone, so that brings me hope :)

Answer (score 1):

I honestly do know if this will help because I haven't received it yet. These boards are intended to be either a transmitter or receiver for bluetooth, and I'm ordering mine for audio. But I saw in one of the feedback comments that a buyer didn't know how well it worked for audio, but that it worked well for USB. I'm not sure how that would work, and in typical aliexpress manner, details beyond a diagram of connections is all you get. But it might be worth looking into. https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805208349147.html

Comment: Yes, I think the best option may be to create exactly what I need with arduino 5GHz wifi modules, thx!